# MySQL has exceeded the 'max_connections_per_hour'

Tags: mysql, magento

My magento website is down, and Hostgator support said that my database is the problem.
I only found the error below. could you help me Please

"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1226] User 'dbuser' has exceeded the 'max_connections_per_hour' resource (current value: 1)"

Comment: So raise the limit, surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried taking these steps:

https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/4274567-how-to-fix-max_connections_per_hour-mysql-error